# Gradient of a scalar-valued function with respect to a matrix

Tags: derivatives, matrix-calculus

Let $\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{y} \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ and $\mathbf{A}, \mathbf{B} \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$.
I am not able to understand why
\begin{equation*}
 \frac{\partial}{\partial \mathbf{B}}(\mathbf{y} - \mathbf{B}^{\top}\mathbf{x})^{\top}\mathbf{A}(\mathbf{y} - \mathbf{B}^{\top}\mathbf{x}) = 4 \mathbf{x}\mathbf{y}^{\top}\mathbf{A} - 4 \mathbf{x}\mathbf{x}^{\top}\mathbf{B}\mathbf{A}.
\end{equation*}
Can you help me understand the passages?

Maybe you need that
\begin{equation*}
 (\mathbf{y} - \mathbf{B}^{\top}\mathbf{x})^{\top}\mathbf{A}(\mathbf{y} - \mathbf{B}^{\top}\mathbf{x}) = \text{trace}(\mathbf{A}(\mathbf{y} - \mathbf{B}^{\top}\mathbf{x})(\mathbf{y} - \mathbf{B}^{\top}\mathbf{x})^{\top}).
\end{equation*}
I tried some calculations with the Einstein notation, but I am not able to find the result. If you also can point me to some theory which explains hwo to compute these kind of quantities I would be thankful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For convenience, use the following product notation for the trace
$$A:B = {\rm Tr}(A^TB)$$
Define the vector
$$w = (B^Tx-y) \implies dw^T = x^TdB$$
Write the cost function in terms of the new variable. Then find its differential and gradient.
$$\eqalign{
 \phi &= w^TAw \cr&= A:ww^T \cr
d\phi
  &= A:(w\,dw^T+dw\,w^T) \cr
  &= w^T(A+A^T):dw^T \cr
  &= w^T(A+A^T):x^TdB \cr
  &= xw^T(A+A^T):dB \cr
\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial B}
  &= xw^T(A+A^T) \cr
  &= x(x^TB-y^T)(A+A^T) \cr
}$$
If $A=A^T$ then this can be simplified
$$\eqalign{
\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial B}
  &= 2x(x^TB-y^T)A \cr
  &= 2xx^TBA - 2xy^TA \cr
}$$
To make this match the expected result, put factor of $(-2)$ in front of the $\phi$.

**NB:** The *cyclic* property of the trace allows colon products to be rearranged in many equivalent ways, e.g. 
$$\eqalign{ A:BC
 &= BC:A \cr
 &= A^T:(BC)^T \cr
 &= B^TA:C \cr
 &= AC^T:B \cr
 &= \ldots \cr
}$$